# Plot side by side box and whisker plots from two dataframes

Tags: seaborn, boxplot

I'm hoping to take these two box plots and combine them into one image:
[![These are two data files I was able to make box and whisker charts for easily using Seaborn boxplot][1]][1]

The datafile I am using is from multiple excel spread sheets and looks like this:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 2 | 5 | ... |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 1 | ... |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Where the column headers represent hours and the column values are the ones I want to use to create box and whisker plots with.

Currently my code is this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xls = pd.ExcelFile('ControlDayVar.xlsx')
df1= pd.read_excel(xls, 'DE_ControlDays').assign(Location=1)
df2= pd.read_excel(xls, 'DE_FestDays').assign(Location=2)
DE_all =pd.concat([df1,df2])
DE= pd.melt(DE_all, id_vars=['Location'], var_name=['Hours'], value_name='Concentration')
ax= sns.boxplot(x='Hours', y= 'Concentration', hue= 'Location', data=DE)
plt.show()

The result I get is this: 
[![Yikes][2]][2]

I expect my issue has to do with the format of my data files, but any help would be appreciated.Thanks!


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXo6F.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEpi7.jpg
```

Comment: To check the dataset matches the expected format, can you show the result of `DE.head()`?

Comment: Thank for the suggestion! Looking at the DE.head(), the format looks to be correct with concentrations, hours and location being accurately represented. https://imgur.com/lLFnnDA

Comment: Are you sure the column is recognized as a numerical data type ?

Comment: You were absolutely right! Concentration value was being treated as a string due to some lingering characters in the data file. Quick fix and the plots look great. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great ! You're welcome. I'll make a proper answer then.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if somehow the `Concentration` values are not properly recognized as a numerical data type anymore.
In that case, the y-axis can no longer be understood as continuous, which can lead to that "yikes" result.